# Why variable representation plays a role in prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, data-transformation, continuous-data

I am working on binary classification using a random forest, where the data have 977 records and 6 columns. The class ratio is 77:23.

I have two derived input variables. One variable is called `no_of_non_responses`, and the other is called as `percentage_of_non_responses`.

Both variables are computed from the same original columns (`no_of_times_called` and `no_of_times_responded`). For example, if I call a customer 10 times and he responds only 4 times, we can know that his value for `no_of_non_responses` is 6 and `percentage_of_non_responses` is 60.

But in my ML model, I see that only `no_of_non_responses` seems to improve predictive power by 2 points (78 to 80), whereas `percentage_of_non_responses` doesn't do that.

But usually, percentages give a better idea of the variable (in this case non response %) when compared to count.

Can I know why it is that, despite representing the same info in two different forms, one improves the predictive power whereas the other doesn't?

Comment: You say *But usually, percentages give a better idea of the variable (in this case non response %) when compared to count*  which is strange, because 1 of 3 and 10 of 30 is same %, but counts preserve more information about variability ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - I say % gives better idea. Let's consider two scenarios for customer A and Customer B. Customer A was called 10 times and Customer B was called 2 times. Both didn't respond only once. Meaning, Customer A's non response count is 1 and customer B non response count is also 1. But if you look at the % of non-response, it is 10% for customer A and 50% for customer B. So, % gives better idea of what is non-response rate of a customer is. If we stick to count, I get 1 for both the customers (but customer B was called only 2 times)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - `When you mean counts preserve more information about variability`, can I know why do you say that? Is there any resource that you can share that help me understand better as to why count is better than %? Also your thoughts on why count is better than %?